# Is a gentile obliged to get married and multiply?

Tags: marriage, mitzvah, olam-haba-world-to-come

We all know that a Jew is obliged to get married and have children. It's considered that a man is not complete until he gets married. I am not sure if a Jew won't have a share in Olam HaBa if he/she didn't get married.

Anyway, if a righteous gentile didn't want or couldn't get married, will he be still considered righteous and will have a share in the world to come ?

Comment: Well, it's not in the 7 noahide laws (unless is somehow included in one), but the torah says 'lasheves yetzarah' which means that mankind was created to populate the world.

Comment: As an aside, given that there are more factors involved than a man simply deciding he wants to have kids, not having kids wouldn't automatically make someone not righteous, even if it is an obligation. If a person 'couldn't get married', or other factors beyond his control, then he isn't held accountable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In בכורות דף מז, there is a dispute as to whether someone who had children and then converted had fulfilled the mitzvah of פרו ורבו, the commandment for Jews to have children. R' Yochanan says he has, for there is a commandment for even gentiles to have children, as the Torah says לשבת יצרה, mankind was created to multiply. Resh lakish argued because a convert is like a new person.

So, gentiles need to have children.

I don't know if they're considered righteous gentiles if they don't but keep the 7 noahide laws.